# Defer all script-Tags

Tags: javascript, parsing

Is there a way to add a defer-Attribute to ALL `<script>-tags` without doing it manually?
Because I want to defer an included external js-file, but this is required for other function on the website.

Comment: How many scripts are you including in the page?

Comment: 3 files are included in the header-file, which is included on every page.
But most pages contain extra script-Tags which would make it hard to change ALL of them

Comment: adding a defer attribute doesn't guarantee that a script will be deferred.

Comment: Well, Google's PageSpeed Test recommends me to parse Javascript after the site has finished loading. Is there another way to do this? It's kind of difficult because I have much inline-js on nearly every page.

Comment: @TobiasBaumeister somebody suggested to put the scripts at the bottom of the page (for some reason the comment was then deleted)

Comment: But then again, inline code won't work

Comment: Time to start using unobtrusive _JavaScript_. Edit: In fact, if I were having to deal with lots of scripts like this, I'd make a script to import them through _JavaScript_ rather than having lots of `<script>` tags written into the _HTML_.